# Rails 4 : How to change the size of text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to change the size of text_field, but it doesn't work.

new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, size: 10 %>
```

`size: 10` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to do this with CSS or HTML?

Comment: You could use `CSS` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked example, you doing some wrong, i belive you have some css style that override you text field :

```
<%= f.text_field :user, size: 10 %>
```

[image][image][image][image]

If i delete `class` from submit, place `</br>`, set 0 `width` in css, and now i see `size` of the `text_field`

[image]

[image]

I hope you understand this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work. The following error appears. "ArgumentError in Users#new" "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Зелёный. As you pointed out, I have some css style that override text_field `input{width: 100%;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `size` option was there

```
 <%= f.text_field :name, :size=>"10" :maxlength=>"254" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work. Although I tried `<%= f.text_field :name, :size=>"10" %>`, the size of text_field remained the same. I tried `<%= f.text_field :name, :size=>"10" :maxlength=>"254" %>`, the following error appears. "SyntaxError in UsersController#new", "e:/xxx/_fields.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...text_field :name, :size=>"10" :maxlength=>"254" );@output_bu... ... ^"

Comment: @SamuraiBlue you miss coma `:size=>"10", :maxlength=>"254"`

Comment: @Зелёный Thank you for your comment. No error appears after adding comma `<%= f.text_field :name, :size=>"10", :maxlength=>"25" %>`, but the size of text_field didn't change.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue try this `<%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, :maxlength => 254, :size => 10 %>`

Comment: @Зелёный Thank you for your speedy response. But the size of text_field didn't change.